# JSON format convert

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

Already I have this below format:

```
[
   {
      user_id:"UID20",
      first_name:"Vasanthis",
      email:"vasanthi.g@redbeaninc.com"
   },
   {
      user_id:"UID19",
      first_name:"Murali",
      email:"murali.m@redbeaninc.com"
   }
];
```

I need to convert like below format:

```
[
   {
      "user_id":[
         "UID20",
         "UID19"
      ],
      "first_name":[
         "Vasanthis",
         "Murali"
      ],
      "email":[
         "vasanthi.g@redbeaninc.com",
         "murali.m@redbeaninc.com"
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see that?

Comment: What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that iterates over the array and extracts the propertynames and values, and puts them in a new object like so:

```
function arrObjToObjArr(a){
  var newObj = {};

  $.each(a, function(k,v) {
    $.each(v, function(prop, val) {
      (newObj[prop] == undefined) ? newObj[prop] = [val] : newObj[prop].push(val);
    });
  });
  return newObj;
}
```

See this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o56pmk38/